# How to make nice content manager approval page?

Tags: views, nodes

The client wants to allow users to upload files but only publish the ones that are approved by the content managers. The content managers want a nice way to flip through pictures and quickly accept or reject pictures.

I created a view where someone can flip through unpublished pictures.

Is there a way to add a check box that corresponds to the the published checkbox in the add content? Basically be able to edit the content within this simple view, but all they would need to edit is published/unpublished.

Any Ideas. Hopefully there is a way to do this without another module, but I'm not picky at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess [Views Bulk Operations (VBO)](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) may help you here. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... This module augments [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) by allowing bulk operations to be executed on the displayed rows. It does so by showing a checkbox in front of each node, and adding a select box containing operations that can be applied. Drupal Core or [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) actions can be used.